# Is there any way to skip the resolver(for a component) when navigating to any route and go directly to the component?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Hello I am new to angular and stuck in a situation. I have a component named `OrderDetailComponent` and a Resolver named  `OrderDetailResolver` as the name implies the resolver resolve the data for order detail component and pass to it. I have a situation when I navigate through `router.navigate(['order', myorder.id, 'detail']);` I do not want `OrderDetailResolver` to resolve the data and directly go to the `OrderDetailComponent`.

I searched on the internet and didnot found any solution to it. Yes I can pass some data in query param and check in the resolver for that and skip the process and return from resolver. But I want to know is there a solution to totally skip the `OrderDetailResolver`.

Comment: Maybe with a guard?

Comment: So, why you're using the resolver?!

Comment: @nimeresam for resolving the data before the routing take place, you can see the official doc [link](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: @InferOn how to do it with guard I did not found anything for this.

Comment: @NaveenSingh my point is: if you want to totally skip the resolver then why you use it?

Comment: @nimeresam I want the resolve the request when going form component A but not when going through component B.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with a work around like the following

inside the resolver

```
const extraState = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
        if (extraState && extraState.skipResolver) {
            return of(null);
        }
```

and when navigating you can do

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/some-url', {state: {
                skipResolver: true,
            }})
```